# .NET: How to build a DLL from source code without the referenced DLL?

Tags: .net, dll, reflection

Look at the following code of a .NET class library:

```
public class Test
{
    public void LogTransaction(Transaction t)
    {
         Logger.Log(t.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can see that class **Transaction** and **Logger** are defined in another DLL, which this DLL references.

I need to write some code to build the above source code into a .NET class library. If I don't have the other DLL, is there anyway my code can build this DLL? I know Visual  Studio will not build if the other DLL is missing.

Comment: Rewrite the DLL from scratch? Decompile it? Hard to know what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reference the required assembly at build time, my suggestion is to create a late-binding wrapper class that works via reflection to create the object and invoke the members.

i.e.

```
public class TransactionWrapper
{
    private object _transaction;

    public TransactionWrapper()
    {
        _transaction = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Transaction"));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var mi = _metadata.GetType().GetMethod("ToString");
        return (string) mi.Invoke(_metadata, null);
    }

    ... // continue with necessary members
}
```

Obviously this technique introduces a number of challenges, chief of which is no compile time safety for the calling convention.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer! Another option may be to produce an "empty" DLL which has the same public interface of the real DLL (that I do not have access at build time), to compile and build my DLL. This "empty" DLL has all the public types and functions, only all the functions contains no implementations. Then, at run time, this "empty" DLL is replaced by the read DLL. Is it doable?

Comment: That would be difficult, if not impossible due to how types and assemblies are loaded and referenced. At compilation dependencies are created to the referenced implementation, to allow these to be swapped, the dummy implementations would need to have the same assembly qualified names including public key (and strong key if actual implementation assembly is signed) as those of the types they will be replaced with.

Comment: Is it technically possible to have the dummy DLL to have the same public strong key?